# Intuition behind $f^{−1}([R_i,∞])$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have been examining these two definitions/prepositions:

> Let $X ⊂ \mathbb R^n$ be a finite union of boxes. A step function
>   is a function $f : X → [0, ∞)$ such that:
>
> (i) the range of $f$ contains only finitely many values $R_1 < · · · < R_k$, and
>
> (ii) for each $i = 1, . . . , k$, the set
>   $f^{-1}([R_i,∞])= \{ x ∈ \mathbb R^n: f(x) ≥ R_i \}$ is a union of finitely many boxes

-

> If $X ⊆ \mathbb R^n$ is a finite union of boxes and $f : X → [0,∞)$
>   is a step function, then $S_f$ is a union of finitely many boxes. In particular,
>   $f$ is integrable.
>
> Proof: Let $R_1 < · · · < R_k$ be all the points in the range of X. For each
>   $i = 1, . . . , k$, set $A_i:= f^{−1}([R_i,∞])$.
>   This is a union of finitely many boxes. Observe that
>   $S_f =\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}
> Ai × [0, Ri
> ]$,
>   which is a finite union of boxes.

This may be completely trivial but I am struggling to understand the concept of $f^{−1}([R_i,∞])$, what it is exactly and its significance in these defintions.  [If this is the graph of $f(x)$ and $S_f$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlUfx.png), is there a way to show $f^{−1}([R_i,∞])$ in this way? 
Can anyone explain the intuition behind this and why it is necessary to know this?

Comment: It is the parts of the domain where $f$ is larger than each $R_i$. Thus in your example there are $R_1,R_2,R_3$, so $f^{-1}([R_1,\infty))$ is the whole domain, $f^{-1}([R_2,\infty))$ is the first two intervals (up until the second jump) and $f^{-1}([R_3,\infty))$ is the second interval (in between the first and second jumps). I'm not really sure why they are doing it this way, though, rather than by looking at, say, $f^{-1}([R_{i-1},R_i])$.

Comment: You mean the graph that I linked? Do I disregard the third 'dip' in the graph because it is less than $f$? Sorry for the poor description

Comment: I've added a second graph, is this what you mean? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The drop between the second and third intervals causes $A_1$ and $A_2$ to be different ($A_2$ does not contain that third interval).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f^{-1}([R_i,\infty])$ is the **set** of all numbers $x$ such that $f(x) \geq R_i$. In words, it is the set of numbers whose image is greater or equal to $R_i$.

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind showing me how the points $R_i$ would look on a graph like the one I linked? Just so I can visualize it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlUfx.png

Comment: Let's say that your graph represents a function such that $f(x)=3$ for $x$ between 1 and 3 and between 6 and 8, $f(x)=5$ for $x$ between 3 and 5, and $f(x)=1$ for x between 5 and 6. Then $f^{-1}([5,\infty])=[3,5]$, $f^{-1}([3,\infty])=[1,5]\cup [6,8]$ and $f^{-1}([1,\infty])=[1,8]$.

Comment: The values $R_i$ are the values taken by the function. In our examples, they are $1$, $3$ and $5$. As far as I understand, your "graph 2" makes no sense at all.

Comment: Ah, I understand! Thank you very much.